# dnsmasq - Multiple dhcp ranges based on client's domain name

Tags: dhcp, dnsmasq

I'm trying to enable multiple DHCP IP ranges on dnsmasq where IP assignments would be based on clients FQDNs (or domain name parts).

I found that dnsmasq has options like dhcp-match which can be combined with dhcp-range by tags.

Unfortunately, i'm not able to get it working and i don't know if dnsmasq cannot do that or if i'm configuring it wrong or maybe just clients don't send their domains/fqdns in DHCPREQUEST.

Could someone help and tell me how this should be configured or maybe how to force requiring domain/fqdn from clients?

My current (not working) part of configuration:

```
dhcp-match=set:dev,15,dev.some.domain.com
dhcp-range=dev,10.0.1.1,10.0.1.99,24h

dhcp-match=set:stg,15,stg.some.domain.com
dhcp-range=stg,10.0.2.1,10.0.2.99,24h

dhcp-match=set:demo,15,demo.some.domain.com
dhcp-range=demo,10.0.3.1,10.0.3.99,24h

# default for all others
dhcp-range=eth0,10.0.0.1,10.0.0.99,24h
```

I also say, that i see in logs only 2 tags (eth0 and dev) and i have no idea why:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 tags: dev, eth0
```

But all ranges as available:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 available DHCP range: 10.0.0.1 -- 10.0.0.99
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 available DHCP range: 10.0.1.1 -- 10.0.1.99
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 available DHCP range: 10.0.2.1 -- 10.0.2.99
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 available DHCP range: 10.0.3.1 -- 10.0.3.99
```

And also interesting logs which helps me not much:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 client provides name: app-01
(...)
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 requested options: 1:netmask, 28:broadcast, 2:time-offset, 121:classless-static-route,
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 requested options: 15:domain-name, 6:dns-server, 12:hostname,
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 requested options: 40:nis-domain, 41:nis-server, 42:ntp-server,
dnsmasq-dhcp[32591]: 3384474735 requested options: 26:mtu, 119:domain-search, 3:router
```

Thanks and regards!